# Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Syncronization with MS SyncFrameWork 1.0 too slow

Tags: windows, mobile, microsoft-sync-framework

For Windows Mobile 6.5.3 we use MS SyncFrameWork 1.0 with  WCF web service to sync data between local sdf and SQL 2012 Database server. 
When we download data, we get an out of memory exception, so we use batching.
With batching the syncronization is too slow, because of using the timestamp field.
With snapshot, the download data process is much faster, but we can't upload data to the server, because there is no timestamp.
The size of the sdf in the begining was 7MB, after 2 weeks it was 20 MB.

What is the best way to do the Syncronization for Windows Mobile 6.5.3?
If MS SyncFrameWork 1.0, than what's your suggestion the handle problems below?

Thanks any suggestion in advice!

Answer (score 0):

one of the thing you can optimize is the dataset serialization. have a look at this [post](https://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2010/03/08/sync-framework-wcf-based-synchronization-for-offline-scenario-%E2%80%93-using-custom-dataset-serialization/) on using dataset surrogates. You can also try to clear the various datasets added in the Sync Context